# You don't have permission to access /bannedwords on this server

Tags: apache, url, yii2

i got a problem in Yii2 urlManager pretty URL. When I write in URL

```
www.sitename/egitim-fakultesi
```

or

```
www.sitename/uzaktan-egitim
```

Because Of The Url contains "**egitim**" words, I get an error "

> You don't have permission to access /uzaktan-egitim on this server.

" 
But when I write in URL:

```
www.sitename/veteriner-fakultesi
```

it's ok!
I cannot figure out to this problem i'm getting crazy! Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you provide your UrlManager configuration?

Comment: And Also When I write in URL:`www.sitename/frontend/web/index.php?r=site/index&birimAdSeo=egitim-fakultesi&language=tr ` its OK

Comment: `''urlManager' => [
 'class' => 'frontend\components\ZUrlManager',
 'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
 'showScriptName' => false,
 'rules' => [
  '<language:en>/'=>'site/index',
  '/'=>'site/index',
  '<language:en>/<birimAdSeo>/'=>'site/birimindex',
  '/<birimAdSeo>/'=>'site/birimindex',
  ]
]'`

Comment: Any chance for the code of `ZUrlManager` class?

Comment: Yes I have changed ZUrlManager but its not contain **egitim** words.

Comment: It's hard to say what is the problem based only on the given info here. If this is real path check if the folder/file exists, if this is rewritten path check the controller responsible for rendering and/or any other internal "gates" like UrlManager, AccessControl and potential external ones.

Comment: What does egitim mean in your language? Also, can you search for the string "egitim" in the whole project? Is it possible that somewhere egitim is mistakenly typed instead of legitim?

Comment: meaning of egitim is education.And also in config file:`'/<birimAdSeo>/'=>'site/birimindex'` code is problem.İf I change like this `'site/<birimAdSeo>/'=>'site/birimindex',` its solved. But I dont want it

Comment: Oppss, I'm sory.. you are right. I use **gi**t in .htaccess file like this.`# Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>` I remove **git** its solved thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

in .htaccess file I had used "git" word:
`# Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>`
and I remove "git" word, its solved...

Comment: You changed .json|.lock|.git to .json|.lock and it worked?